# Can "ready" come in sentences without being preceded by "get/be"?

Tags: sentence-structure, adjectives, word-order

I found "ready" in sentences preceded by either the verb **get** or **be** when it functions as an adjective, not a noun, like the following:

- She was ready to take the exam.
- Get ready for what will happen next.

I want to use it but in a different structure as this one:

> You wrote that while putting the candy between your teeth **ready** to eat it.

So, is the position of "ready", in the sentence above, correct?

Comment: *"Ready or not, here I come."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is correct except for the punctuation. It needs a comma.

> You wrote that while putting the candy between your teeth, ready to eat it.

(“putting the candy...” and “ready to eat it” both describe what *you* were doing/feeling while writing)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the sentence

> You wrote that while putting the candy between your teeth **ready** to eat it.

Sounds perfectly correct to me.